# MySql and PHP Time Overlapping

Tags: php, mysql

For example i have the following Time to be inserted:

```
7 am to 12pm
```

And the data in my database are:

```
8 am to 9 am ,
11 am to 1 pm ,
5 am to 7 am
```

what `'WHERE'` statement do i need to add in my `'SELECT'` statement so that if it returns a value then it means That current time is already `'RESERVED'` if not then its ' `AVAILABLE '`

My current code is

```
select eventDate,timestart,timeend from eventcalendar where eventDate='$eventdate' and
 ((Cast('$timestart' as time) > timestart  and Cast('$timestart' as time) < timeend) or  
 (Cast('$timeend' as time) > timestart  and Cast('$timeend' as time) < timeend)) or 
((Cast('$timestart' as time) between timestart and timeend) or ((Cast('$timeend' as time) between timestart and timeend)))
```

Comment: can you please explain more.? what is your problem?

Comment: My Problem is that when i insert the value 7am to 12pm , it overlaps with 8 am to 9 am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally solved it by adding and reverse the given

```
"select eventDate,timestart,timeend from eventcalendar where eventDate='$eventdate' and 
 ((Cast('$timestart' as time) > timestart  and Cast('$timestart' as time) < timeend) or  
 (Cast('$timeend' as time) > timestart  and Cast('$timeend' as time) < timeend)) or 

  (timestart >  Cast('$timestart' as time) and timestart < Cast('$timeend' as time))  or
(timeend >  Cast('$timestart' as time) and timeend < Cast('$timeend' as time))   "
```